# Modelling population movement within a city.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, mathematical-modeling

The semester break is here and I'm working on a startup. One of the project requires me to determine the movement of population within a highly-dense city in light of variables as such time of the day, parts of a week, how large scale events affects the movement of population across different parts of the city. 
Why is this interesting? 
Take Uber as a case example: 
Uber slaps surge pricing on consumers if the pick-up destination of their choice experiences a greater demand than supply. While this works in the favour of Uber drivers, this certainly means more pay out to Uber drivers by Uber. More pertinently, this suggests poor allocation of resources to areas of greater demand where areas of lower demand could be experiencing a greater supply of Uber drivers.

Any suggestion as to good resources and the mathematics to get me started would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think this is a very broad question.  If you gave values or even ranges for some of the things you're interested in, e.g. density, it would help.  Also, keep in mind you may find it difficult to get any meaningful values for what you're doing.  While it helps to have trends for Chicago, the same model may not transfer easily to Detroit, New York, etc.  You may be looking at a model that is non-linear (dynamic/chaotic) rather than linear.

Comment: @floorcat What about the use of stochastic process and Markov chain to perform such modelling? Are they viable candidates?

Comment: The definition of "stochastic" is that there may be statistical patterns, but that no prediction can be made from the data.  The issue still remains of finding any meaningful data, where "meaningful" is any data point that allows successful predictions.   With a Markov chain, the chain must satisfy the property of making a prediction.  You can use probability thresholds to allow state transitions, but if the system is nonlinear, or chaotic, then the complexity would be too great over time to allow any efficient states to transition from or to.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @floorcat Yes it does. The explanation you gave have been helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically Sim City.

http://m.ign.com/wikis/simcity/Traffic

> Traffic moves in predictable patterns. Generally speaking, your Sims leave their homes in a residential zone in the morning, and then take the nearest route to their jobs, either commercial or industrial. They'll stay there until the mid-afternoon (around 5pm), then drive back. Traffic to and from entertainment venues during their off-hours is not simulated; check out the zone relationships page for more information.
>
> If you want to fully figure out your city's situation, watch the traffic flow during 9am and 5pm, the two “rush hours” (which in truth last more than an hour until you get mass transit in the city). Generally speaking, the more options you have between your residential and industrial neighborhoods, the better your traffic flow will be, as your Sims will be less inclined to take the exact same route as all their neighbors.

Here is some raw data for you on real cities, you can extrapolate to whatever you are investigating.

https://www.google.com/amp/www.citylab.com/amp/article/364604/?client=ms-android-hms-tmobile-us

Comment: Interesting. I have had exposure to traffic dynamics but it isn't exactly clear to me whether traffic dynamics itself is a sufficient candidate itself for modelling population movement within a city.